# RailsでFactoryGirlを利用してSeed.rbファイル作成

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Ruby on Railsで開発しています。
FactoryGirlを利用してSeed.rbファイルを作成し、テストデータを用意しようと思っています。
ところで、各テーブルごとに10個以上のデータが必要ですが、どうすればいいですか？

例えば
spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    id { Faker::Number.between(1, 50) }
    name { Faker:Name:name }
    phone_number { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
  end
end
```

このファイルを使ってSeeds.rbから50個ぐらい作るとしたらどうすればいいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeds.rbの中で

```
50.times do
  create :user
end
```

のようにすれば50件のuserデータが作成できます。

ちなみに、質問のコードにある id は通常DBが自動的に付与するので指定しなくても構いません。
むしろ自分でランダムに指定すると偶然idがかぶってしまったときにユニークキー制約エラーになって、データが作成できなくなります。

なので以下のように定義する方がベターです。

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker:Name:name }
    phone_number { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
  end
end
```

### 追記

> これでできるんでしょうかね..

まずはご自身で試してみてその結果を書いてもらった方が、早く問題を解決できると思います。（そもそも、元々の質問は「50件ぐらいのテストデータを作るためには？」という内容なので、FactoryGirl自体はすでにseeds.rbの中で動いているものだとこちらは認識していました）

実際に試してはいませんが、参考になりそうな情報がありました。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7402054/1058763

上記の回答とコメントの内容を参考にするとこんな感じで使えるようになるみたいです。

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
end

# db/seeds.rb
require 'factory_girl_rails'

50.times do
  FactoryGirl.create :user
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
require 'factory_girl_rails' # <= 追加
```

繰り返しになりますが、こちらでは動作確認していないので、まずはKimさんの環境で動かしてみて下さい。

Comment: db/seeds.rb >

require 'factory_girl'
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/factories/*.rb')].each {|f| require f }

50.times do
  FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end


これでできるんでしょうかね..